# Compares two values from Mysql with the Spring Framework using the Equals statement

Tags: java, mysql, spring

How to compare 2 values from Mysql table using Equals or another. I tried but the statement structure is not valid. Such as

User.java

```
public class User {
private long id;
//getter and setter
}
```

Address. Java

```
public class Address {
private long id 
//getter and setter

}
```

and I also created 2 service classes: findByID (long id) of 2 entities

I am trying to make a comparison like this

Controller.java

```
 @Getmapping("/test)
public ModelAndView test ( ModelAndView modelAndView, User user, Address address ){
User users = userService.findById (user.getId );
Address addresses = addressService.findById (address.getId );
if (users.equals.addresses){
modelAndView.setViewName("success");
else {
 modelAndView.setViewName ("Error");
     }
return modelAndView;
```

Table user.sql
id = 1

Table address.sql
id =1

I get an error in the If statement when comparing two values. Although I have not run the program yet but the IDE reports 2 values are uses and addresses do not match. How do I compare correctly? Thank you very much

Comment: `equals` is a *method call*, not a *statement*, and as such should be written `if (users.equals(addresses)) {`

Comment: Your variable names are misleading. `users` but it only refers to 1 user, and `addresses` but it only refers to 1 address. They should be named `user` and `address`.

Comment: `users.equals(addresses)` will always be `false`, because a user cannot be an address. It's like comparing a car to a fruit, they can never be the same.

Comment: Unless the address `id` is a foreign key to the user `id`, the id's in the two tables are unrelated. However, if you need to compare them in Java, use `if (user.getId() == address.getId()) {`. Since id's a primitive `long` values, you compare them using `==`.

Comment: Do I need to write a statement to get value from Service for example: User user = userService. findById (user.getId) and Address. Then compare them with each other or just get Id from entity user.getId to compare with Address?

Comment: Don't understand that comment, since you're already getting both objects from the Service, and I just [showed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63707226/compares-two-values-from-mysql-with-the-spring-framework-using-the-equals-statem?noredirect=1#comment112656156_63707226) how to get id values from both objects and comparing them, so why would you ask if you need to write a statement doing that?